# IN clause with values or nested select query?

Tags: mysql, database, authorization

I have requirement for which I have a small confusion and need some suggestions from you. I have user object and the list of site_ids for which he has permissions. So my doubt is, do I have to cache these permissions and use them in the IN of the query to perform some other operations or do not cache them, instead use a nested query in the IN clause to fetch the site_ids?
As there is either memory or db access trade-off will be there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

If I understand correctly, your question is:

- Should I create complicated logic to move data from the database to my application and back to the database?
- Or, should I do all the processing in the database?

You should do all the processing in the database.  Why bother having multiple queries and application-level logic when that is not needed?

If you do need the ids in the application, then there are arguments for constructing the query there.  Notably, the underlying data could change and you might want a consistent interface for the user.

MySQL does a good job of optimizing `in` with lists of constants.  Apart from the overhead of running multiple queries and doing client-side processing, the `IN` with many constants should have good performance.